# Binding class properties to UserControl in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have a class that contains a string property called Text.

```
   public class Time
    {
        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; } 
            set { _text = value; }
        }
    }
```

I also have a custom UserControl which contains this class.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
<...>
    private Time _myTime;
    public Time MyTime
    {
            get { return _myTime; }
            set { _myTime= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
    }
}
```

From my ViewModel, I want to create the above UserControl and assign to it a Time class and all of its properties:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Time TestTime = new Time();
    TestTime.Text = "Hello world";

    MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl();
    control.MyTime = TestTime;

    controlViewer = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Control>();
    controlViewer.Add(control);
        // on my main window, I have an ItemsControl with 
        // ItemsSource="{Binding controlViewer}".
}
```

The XAML for the UserControl contains this TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTime.Text}"/>
```

I am then able to call the control.MyTime.Text property programmatically and get the "Hello world" value just fine -- but I can't get it to show on the newly created MyUserControl's textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the source object of the binding to the UserControl instance, e.g. by setting the Binding's `RelativeSource` property like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTime.Text,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

Besides that, it is uncommon to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in a view element. You might instead declare `MyTime` as dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyTime", typeof(Time), typeof(MyControl));

public Time MyTime
{
    get { return (Time)GetValue(MyTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyTimeProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not so good practice to create the UserControl in your ViewModel. 
Try to do that in the next way:

1. Create the XAML main window with the ItemsControl(the ListView/ListBox is better since they allow selection).
2. Create the ViewModel with ObservableCollection of Time class objects, then bind this ViewModel to the MainWindow as a view model.
3. Initialize the ViewModel with objects you want to see in your collection.
4. Define the DataTemplate for each your ItemsControl collection members, using your UserControl.

Regards,